# datastax[DSI] interneal error - SwapWriteError while using with tableau

Tags: tableau-api, datastax-enterprise, apache-spark-sql

I'm using DataStax-4.6. I'm trying to do some some reports with tableau using Cassandra data. I have datastax ODBC driver installed.

I'm executing the SQL  query in tableau via new custom SQL option in tableau and I'm getting the below error while loading data (applying joins on Cassandra tables).

```
**datastax[DSI] internal error - SwapWriteError**
```